# Persist Geolocation Data with React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation, storage

I am building an app with geolocation. If the user does not have an internet connection, I need to store the geolocation data in the app and then send it to a web server as a JSON array once the device reconnects to the internet and clear the data stored locally.

I was thinking about storing the data using AsyncStorage, which I understand works similarly to the browser's LocalStorage. What concerns me is that there might be major performance issues if I have to parse and serialize the data on every geolocation update. What other possibilities are there for storing data that is being generated with high frequency in React Native?

Comment: what approach did you follow here?

Comment: I went with async storage. After some testing, the amount of data was small enough that no other library was required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use realm DB(https://realm.io/blog/introducing-realm-react-native), it is very useful for the cases when you have large amount of data to store locally.

You can store your data in your app store(Redux or Mobx) when your app is running and push the data in realm db when you exit your app or when it goes in background.

When your connection comes back you can just retrieve the data from realm db and send it to your server, You can use NetInfo for listening to Network Connectivity Changes.

Answer (score 1):

For a small amount of data storage and retrieval, AsycnStrage is the best choice, and there will be no problems in performance.

Of course, the use of AsyncStorage may be relatively complicated. You can also use a third-party library [react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md) to assist you in using AsyncStorage. It can allow AsyncStorage access to support strings, Boolean types, objects, etc., and it can also support direct access and synchronous access in the form of assignment. Persistent storage.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that new geolocation data will be generated with high frequency (at least once every few seconds). So if the cumulative data has't been dispatched to the server in say 5 hours, thats quite a bit information to be stored in AsyncStorage isn't it? Will checkout your mentioned library to see if it fits my needs. Thanks again.